Is everything is Buddha nature?
I read the following on the internet:

Everything is Buddha nature.

Is everything is Buddha nature? Please provide answers from established Buddhist traditions which teach the concept of Buddha Nature.

Please refer to The Buddha-nature in Dogen's
Shobogenzo
by Takashi James Kodera.

All things are sentient beings, all things are the Buddha-nature; the
Tathagata  abides constantly, is non-existent yet existent, and is the
change.

...

From the beginningless past many foolish people identified consciousness and spirituality as the Buddha-nature. How laughable it is that they were called the enlightened people. If I were to explain the Buddha-nature without getting too involved, [I would say that it is] fences, walls, roof tiles,
and pebbles.

...

What “all things are sentient beings” means, according to  the Way of
the Buddha, is that all things that possess the  “mind” are sentient
beings; this is because the “mind” is the  mark of sentient beings.
Those [said to be] without the  “mind” must also be sentient beings;
this is because “all sentient beings” are the “mind”. Therefore, all
that possess  the “mind” are the sentient beings, and the sentient
beings  all have the Buddha-nature. Grass, trees, land ... are all
“mind.” Since they are the “mind,” they are sentient beings; since
they are all sentient beings, they have the Buddha-nature.  This is
what the National Master [Yen-kuan] means by the  existence of the
Buddha-nature. If it were not meant in this  way, it would not be the
Buddha-nature that is meant by the  Way of the Buddha.

-- the quotes are from Dogen's Shobogenzo. There is some useful analysis in Takashi's research, if you care to read.
In my own words, there's no dualistic distinction between mind and matter. They are not two distinct essences. Mind is interaction of matter. Matter itself is nothing other than interaction. Therefore, there's no essential difference between the sentient beings and the insentient things, let alone between Buddhas and beings, they are all essentially of the same nature. This is why we can say everything is Buddha Nature, spontaneously abiding, always in flux, devoid of essential duality, and inherently capable of semiosis.

Thank you @Andriy Volkov, very interesting.

Yes. Everything is Buddha nature. Except you.
The question shows that the student thinks Buddha nature is something obtained.
To have them think on not having Buddha nature, brings one back to remembering Buddha nature, is not something you obtain from the outside, but something we remember having all along.
(Thank you to Brendan Darrer for the link & edit.)

In Mahayana there is a concept of Buddha Nature which states every being is capable of enlightenment.
In my opinion , which is largely logical, is that until there is craving , the Buddha nature can not arise. Buddha nature is conditional. We can not say Buddha nature does not exist or that Buddha nature always exist. Buddha nature is conditional meaning Buddha nature arises when conditions are met.

In Theravada, a Bodhisatta develops the 10 paramita to the highest to become a Buddha.
This is a very difficult process.
The Buddha explains that there is kusala and akusala (helpful and unhelpful) actions.
So to say that everything is Buddha nature, may be in relation to everything being the three characteristics (impermanence, suffering and not-self).
Though all beings need to purify their actions before Buddhahood or enlightenment, so to say that everything is Buddha Nature, I think this is a very poor oversimplification.
Without Wisdom, Right View and Right action on the Path, how could Buddhahood or enlightenment be possible?

Though all through life the fool might wait upon the wise, no more
Dhamma can he sense than spoon the taste of soup. Dhammapada 64
Though briefly one intelligent might wait upon the wise, quickly
Dhamma he can sense as tongue the taste of soup. Dhammapada 65

**will update the quote later*

So I think better to say that Buddha Nature is in wise action that leads to Nibbana.

Everything is Buddha nature!
Is murder Buddha nature? Only in so far as it is a lesson to learn from and then not do it again.
Everything is Buddha nature if you think about, or not think about it as the case may be (thinking can be the problem!). We are talking about essence of each human, animal, plant and mineral, underneath the layers of illusion.
The illusion is not the Buddha nature.
There has to be a positive outcome for eveything in the end! Otherwise its just madness.

Dhammapada 174. Blind is the world; here only a few possess insight. Only a few, like birds escaping from the net, go to realms of bliss. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.13.budd.html

Everyone returns to the Source eventually, even if it takes many lifetimes. It will work out alright for everyone in the end. Its has to be a positive for everyone and everything. Makes sense to me! Seems fair.

There is no "Source" in Buddhism.

A rose by any other name would taste just as sweet.

The Source of all life is Nirvana.

No. Nibbana is not the source of all life.

Why do you say that?

I am talking about life as in essence/spirit, suffering is of the mind, when the mind tries to think things through, it can't and it suffers "You can't know it, but you can be it, at ease in your own life" - Tao Te Ching (Stephen Mitchel 1988). Even in great physical suffering, if the mind strong it can transcend it. Thinking creates problems. Yes we need to think, but give your brain rest from time to time, and taste peace, it revives you.

Suffering often brings about awakening. Buddha means awakened one.
